# Access Token returned although MFP Server is already Down

Tags: javascript, typescript, callback, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

I shut down the MFP Server purposely and I still can receive/get the access token through the call WLAuthorizationManager.obtainAccessToken().

By comparing the Token I realize that is the same one as before (when the server was running)

First I don't why the WLAuthorizationManager.obtainAccessToken() goes to callback success function and not to the reject function, the second thing is that the token is the same.

this is my checkServer Function:

```
    function mfpServerAvailable() {

    var deferred = $q.defer();

        WLAuthorizationManager.obtainAccessToken().then(function (accessToken) {
            WL.Logger.debug("obtainAccessToken onSuccess: " + JSON.stringify(accessToken));
            deferred.resolve(true);
         }, function (response) {
            WL.Logger.debug("obtainAccessToken onFailure: " + JSON.stringify(response));
            deferred.reject(false);
         });

     return deferred.promise;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the token is already stored in your device and **if its not expired**, then the MF client SDK doesn't communicate with server to fetch new one.

It returns the same access token as long as it is valid.

Comment: so how can I check the MFP server Status? That's my purpose behind that code, otherwise, how can I make the expire the Token by clicking for example on Logout button?

Comment: @HeniG. Call `clearAccessToken(AccessToken accessToken)` API to clear the stored access token. You need to pass accessToken parameter in clearAccessToken  which comes in the success callback of  `obtainAccessToken` API

Comment: @HeniG.Please mark this solution as answered, If its resolves your query.

Comment: @HeniG.,
    If finding/reaching the server is your objective, you could try a WLResoureRequest call to "[runtime-name]/api/reach/" endpoint.

"https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refrest-mfp-server-runtime/html/reachUsingGET.html"